# Get attribute value of childNodes in XML

Tags: android, xml, dom

I'm trying to get the value of the second child in an XML file, but it seems to be difficult for me, so I would be really grateful if you could help me. I need to get the names `Rob`, `Bob` and `Victor` .. without `Tom`. And finally the String expression should be `"//main"`

```
 <main id="Tom">
      <asd name="Rob">
      </asd>
      <qwe name="Bob">
      </qwe>
      <iop name="Victor">
      </iop>
 </main>
```

that's what I do so far...

```
public void getXML(String direction)throws Exception{
    String[] stops = new String[22];
    InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bus_time));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//main" ;
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression,inputSrc,XPathConstants.NODESET);


    if(nodes != null && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            NodeList child = node.getChildNodes();

            for(int k=0; k<child.getLength();k++) {
                Node asd = child.item(k);
                NamedNodeMap attr = asd.getAttributes();
                for (int a = 0; a < attr.getLength(); a++) {
                    stops[a]  = attr.item(a).getNodeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(stops[a]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The result I'm receiving from the Toast = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method node.getChildNodes() returns some elements with type equals TEXT_NODE, this is not the kind you are looking for and it fails when trying to access its attributes. In order to make your code work, you have to check if asd.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE before trying get the attribute you want.
So add this condition to the following piece of your code:

```
if (asd.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {             
  NamedNodeMap attr = asd.getAttributes();
                for (int a = 0; a < attr.getLength(); a++) {
                    stops[a]  = attr.item(a).getNodeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(this, stops[a], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
}
```

But you could make it simpler, you don't need to loop through the attributes to get the specific attribute, just cast it to Element and access it by attribute name, like:

```
if (asd.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {             

  Toast.makeText(this, ((Element)asd).getAttribute("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Or another way:

```
if (asd instanceof Element) {             

  Toast.makeText(this, ((Element)asd).getAttribute("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```